# combinations within groups in R

Tags: r, combinations, igraph, edge-list, group

I have the following DataFrame in R:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001),             
                name= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

I need to create an edge-list for network analysis. For each `id`, I want all the possible combinations (without repetition) of the values in `name`.

Here below is the desired output:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2),
                year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001),             
                name1= c("A", "A", "B", "D"),
                name2= c("B", "C", "C", "E"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `data.table` option using `combn`

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[, as.data.table(t(combn(name, 2))), .(id, year)]
   id year V1 V2
1:  1 2000  A  B
2:  1 2000  A  C
3:  1 2000  B  C
4:  2 2001  D  E
```

Comment: it returns: Error in combn(name, 2) : n < m

Comment: @PineappleP In your real dataframe, one of your groups has less than 2 rows. That's why you get the error. you can try `setDT(df)[, .SD[.N > 1], .(id, year)][, as.data.frame(t(combn(name, 2))), .(id, year)]`

Comment: Or may use `transpose` from `data.table` i.e. `setDT(df)[, data.table::transpose(combn(name, 2, simplify = FALSE)), .(id, year)]`

Comment: @akrun yes, nice proposal of using `transpose`, I believe it would be more efficient than `t`. Thank you bro!